# How to draw 3D Shape in AnyLogic via Code

Tags: java, shapes, anylogic

I want to draw a 3D Shape in AnyLogic via Code, so it is possible to draw by simply using the function. My current idea is something like this:

```
Shape3D obs = new Shape3D ();
// Set the position of the obstacle obs area in 3D space
obs.setPos(xStartCoordinate, yStartCoordinate, zStartCoordinate);
//Set Roation
obs.setRotation(rotation);
//Set XCoordinate
obs.setX(xCoordinate);
//Set YCoordinate
obs.setY(yCoordinate);
//Set ZCoordinate
obs.setZ(zCoordinate);
//Set Visibility
obs.setVisible(visibility);
```

Is there a way to change this a little bit to achieve the goal?

Comment: hi Federico, docu tells that Shape3D is an abstract class. Meaning you cant instantiate it. Look for its subclasses and their constructors: 
AbstractShapeGISMap, ElevatorShaft, Shape3DObject, ShapeEmbeddedObjectPresentation, ShapeGroup, ShapeImage, ShapeLine, ShapeLineFill, ShapeText